# Setting up recaptcha on corporate account?

Tags: recaptcha

I am looking for a way to link recaptcha to a G Suite developer console or some form of non-individual account that will allow me to ensure this is enterprise ready (i.e. won't just fail if someone leaves, can be accessed by multiple devs).

Am I missing something very obvious on this? I can't find a means anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The reCAPTCHA settings allow you to designate multiple owners for each instance:

[image]